# Anti forgery issue with some Android devices

Tags: android, google-chrome, asp.net-core, http-status-code-400, antiforgerytoken

I have a .NET Core 3.1.3 web app that uses anti forgery. Everything works fine on chrome on desktop and some tablets. It works fine on Android devices with Firefox.
However, on Chrome some Android devices with 8.1 on them return 400 errors for any ajax call that has anti forgery enabled.

Some code:

#### Form:

```
<form id="appForm" method="post" role="form">
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken();
```

#### Controller:

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [IgnoreAntiforgeryToken] // adding this to disable anti forgery makes the ajax call work
    //[DisableCors]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<JsonResult> AddProduct(int productId)
    {
```

#### Ajax:

```
 $.ajax({
        url: "/Cart/AddProduct/",
        data: {
            __RequestVerificationToken: $("[name='__RequestVerificationToken']").val(),
            productId: $(this).data("productcode")
        },
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
```

#### Startup.cs

```
 services.AddAntiforgery(o =>
        {
            o.FormFieldName = "__RequestVerificationToken";
            o.HeaderName = "X-XSRF-TOKEN";
            //o.SuppressXFrameOptionsHeader = true;
            o.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
            o.Cookie.Expiration = TimeSpan.FromDays(7);
        });
```

If I turn anti forgery off by adding the attribue **[IgnoreAntiforgeryToken]** to my controller then the ajax call works on the Android device. Otherwise it returns a 400 error.

It works on a device with Android 9.* but not on a phone and tablet with Android 8.1 on them.

Can anybody suggest anything that might causes this?  I am out of ideas and rapidly going bald.

thanks

nb: The explicit use of  @Html.AntiForgeryToken() is not necessary because Core will add a token for any forms with a POST method. But I wanted to try adding it explicitly to see if it solved the issue. Alas no.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be cookie policy. To fix, in startup.cs use:

```
SameSiteMode.Unspecified;
```

Unspecified uses the client requirements. Chrome had been compplaining about Samesite = None.